# How do I sort a list based on its child object attributes?

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics

I'm wondering if someone can elucidate a method to sort a list of objects based on a child object's attribute. 
I'm working with the following model:

```
public class Content
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<ContentAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class ContentAttribute
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Some sample data:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "123",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "Value": "abc",
                "Id": "1a",
                "Name": "name1"
            },
            {
                "Value": "ghi",
                "Id": "2b",
                "Name": "name2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "456",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "Value": "abc",
                "Id": "1a",
                "Name": "name2"
            },
            {
                "Value": "def",
                "Id": "2b",
                "Name": "name3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "789",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "Value": "abc",
                "Id": "1a",
                "Name": "name1"
            },
            {
                "Value": "def",
                "Id": "2b",
                "Name": "name2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I sort the Content objects by the `Value` of a specific attribute `Name`? For example, I would like to sort the above data by the `Value` of 'name2', 
meaning the result would be

```
[
    {"Id" : "456"},
    {"Id" : "789"},
    {"Id" : "123"}
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. (Using c#).

Comment: "I would like to sort the above data by the value of 'name2'" What does this mean? You say you want to sort by a specific value. That doesn't make sense. It's like saying, I want to sort this list by the number 7.

Comment: In the context of the data, the values for 'name2' would be "abc", "def", and "ghi". Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Attributes` always has an element with name `name2` and you want an exception if it doesn't then:

```
var sorted = contents.OrderBy(c => c.Attributes.First(a => a.Name == "name2").Value).ToList();
```

Or if `name2` could be missing and it's not deal breaker then use `FirstOrDefault`

```
var sorted = contents.OrderBy(c => c.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "name2")?.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: If you wanted to be safe you could use:  `c.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "name2")?.Value`

Comment: I'd have added that as additional way because  the exception could have been a way to determine a bug which you now don't have.